# React-spring how to animate letters of an array correctly

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, react-spring, react-motion

In this code with `react-spring` I am getting an animation where each letter waits until the previous animation ends, and also in the meantime it is being animated

Why is this happening, and how could I fix it?

```js
  const text = [...'hey there how are you']
  const from = { transform: 'rotateX(0deg) translateY(0px) rotate(0deg) scale(1)' }
  const to = inView
    ? [
        { transform: 'rotateX(30deg) translateY(10px) rotate(-13deg) scale(1)' },
        { transform: 'rotateX(0deg) translateY(-22px) rotate(3deg) scale(1.1)' },
        { ...from },
      ]
    : from

  const trail = useTrail(text.length, {
    config: { mass: 5, tension: 2000, friction: 200 },
    from: from,
    to: to,
  })

  return (
    <>
      <Div ref={handleRef}>
        {trail.map((props, i) => (
          <animated.span key={`char${i}`} style={props}>
            {text[i] === ' ' ? <>&nbsp;</> : text[i]}
          </animated.span>
        ))}
      </Div>
    </>
  )
```

Comment: What is the desired animation? Do you want all of the letters to move at once? Or for there to be less delay between each letter? Please explain in as much detail as you can how what you currently have is incorrect.

Comment: Just experimenting, I'd like to start all animations at once, and also as you say to have less delay between each letter (currently doesn't seem to be a delay but a sequential animation)

Comment: I think you'd need to look at something other than `useTrail`, as a trail is specifically used for building a list of elements that follow on from each other. Perhaps looks at [useChain](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-chain)

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of useTransition now, trying to reproduce the examples shown here https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-transition but I cannot get the basic ones work (yet) (would be really helpful to have codepens of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `useSprings` I can get independent strings for each item, which I can delay individually

This is done out-of-the-box when the `to:` only has one rule, but if you want to concatenate more rules then somehow each element is not independent of the others

Using `useSprings` you can get this individuality

```js
const text = [...'hey there how are you']
  const from = { transform: 'translate3d(0,0px,0)' }
  const to = inView ? [{ transform: 'translate3d(0,-40px,0)' }, { transform: 'translate3d(0,40px,0)' }] : from

  const base = {
    config: { mass: 5, tension: 2000, friction: 200 },
    from: from,
    to: to,
  }

  const springs = useSprings(text.length, text.map((t, i) => ({ ...base, delay: 100 * i })))

  return (
    <Div ref={handleRef}>
      {springs.map((s, i) => {
        return (
          <animated.span key={`char${i}`} style={s}>
            {text[i] === ' ' ? <>&nbsp;</> : text[i]}
          </animated.span>
        )
      })}
    </Div>
  )
```

Comment: missing `display: "inline-block"`